rails : how desabled override accessor when update
I have a methode to overide a field in category model :
def foo
   _foo = read_attribute(:foo)
   _foo = competition.foo if _foo.nil?
   _foo
end

in controller, the update function :
category.update(foo: params[:foo], bar: params[:bar], baz: params[:baz])

the update dont take the nil value (when params[:foo] = nil), because Rails use override accessor...
I need use the override accessor in my app, but when I update category itself, I need just update the value without use overrided attribute.
How can I do in this case?

is it possible that params will have foo with nil value for saving it?

why not just rename foo method to, for example, something_foo?

yes, its my use case in fact... @dbugger yes I know, that is the problem, but what solution? I don't want use another method to access at this property in my code, I juste need to bypass it during update

I am very confused by the question because you have shown #foo but that has nothing to do with #foo= (which is what assignment would be). This leads me to believe your issue is not that the update doesn't work (it probably works perfectly) but rather that you want this method to both return nil sometimes and return competition.foo sometimes, which is not possible the way you have defined def foo (or really logically at all).

and how do you write foo= to do what i need?
